# Stored Procedure with optional parameters but at least one to be required

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

Is it possible to create a stored procedure that has parameters which are all optional individually, but at least one of the parameters must be provided?

For example, if I have a procedure that updates a record, I must pass in a record id, and then at least one column to update.  The procedure should check to ensure at least one additional parameter/column is provided.

Comment: MSSQL 2008, but it would be good to know if this is a generally available feature or not.

Comment: That sort of feature is very implementation specific. And how it's done in the ones that support it is also very implementation specific.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do this in my programming language of choice instead of a stored proc. Why? This is the type of logic checking that TSQL is not very good at; the syntax for checking this will be  "icky" and it will be slow.

Also, the biggest performance advantage a stored proc gives you is running compiled SQL. In this case, because the SQL needs to be dynamically built, you lose that advantage. Thus, why do it as a stored procedure?

Comment: I had considered this, but thought it might be better practice from a design perspective to put the error checking in the procedure itself, to prevent bad calls of the procedure from doing things it shouldn't be doing.

Comment: I disagree. The error checking in the SP is difficult to get correct within the limitations of TSQL. One of the first challenges is how do you identify a null to update versus a null meaning don't update (i.e. in the first case, you want to update the column's value to null; in the second case you don't want to update the column at all). How you get around that problem will require knowledge of how to pass the parameters to the SP. Plus, unit testing app code is much easier than a SP.

Answer (score 2):

I would put an if statement as the first action.

```
IF @param1 is null and @param2 isnul and @param3 is null
Begin
--steps tpo raise an error or exit the proc
End
```

Comment: This seems like a lot of code if I start having lots of parameters, but perhaps this is unavoidable in SQL?

Comment: This is the only way to enforce it, and it's better than the altenatives (no validation/app validation)

Answer (score 0):

Use the following in where clause

```
where
(isnull(@param1,0)=0 or id=@param1)
and 
(isnull(@param2,'')='' or name=@param2)
```